# Como imprimir um array em forma de string na tela?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Como eu faço para imprimir essa consulta SQL na tela em forma de string?

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$resultado = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE user_id = '$current_user->ID' AND meta_key = '_jm_candidate_field_clocknow_user_btn'" );
```

Essa consulta está retornando o seguinte resultado:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => value_1 ) )
```

Eu gostaria que apenas mostrasse o valor `value_1`.

Comment: `echo $resultado[0]->meta_value`

Comment: Obrigado rray! Funfo :)

Comment: E se eu quiser verificar o $resultado em um IF. Exemplo: if ( $resultado == value 1) { faça uma coisa } else { faça outra coisa }. Como faço? Sou iniciante em PHP.

Comment: É a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como a própria mensagem diz:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => value_1 ) )
```

Sua variável `$resultado` é do tipo `Array`, contendo um valor na posição zero, do tipo `stdClass`, cujo possui um atributo `meta_value`. Para acessá-lo, devemos primeiro recuperar o respectivo objeto:

```
$resultado[0]
```

Com o objeto, podemos aceesar seu atributo através do operador `->`, como abaixo:

```
$resultado[0]->meta_value;
```

Se quiser ainda efetuar alguma operação com este valor, fica mais didático armazená-lo em uma variável:

```
$value = $resultado[0]->meta_value;
```

Aqui, sua variável terá o valor `value_1`, seguindo o exemplo dado na pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson, era isso que eu precisava! (Só faltou ter armazenado dentro de uma variável).

Comment: Não é um processo necessário. Ter algo como `if ($resultado[0]->meta_value == 1) { ... }` é perfeitamente válido. Armazenar o valor em outra variável apenas deixa mais didático e facilita a compreensão de iniciantes.